# Should we have software-specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Peter and I are apparently of different opinion](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/13545/revisions) on the opportunity of tagging questions with [bibtex](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibtex). He edited a question to add the tag, thus creating it. I thought it wasn't a good tag, because discussion limited to features of one specific piece of software are considered off topic. So, basically, having the tag would lead more people to ask such unwanted questions. So, instead of starting an edit war, let's open a discussion here.

I've pretty much explained my own position case above: **I believe [bibtex](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibtex) as a tag is not a good thing**, no more than [ms-word](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) (which doesn't exist) or [latex](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) (which has 3 questions). It is true that there may be few legitimate on-topic questions that include bibtex, but (i) it's a minority, and the vast majority of questions we get are off topic; (ii) if the question is on topic, it's mainly because bibtex (or any other specific software) is not central to it.

But I'm wondering how the community feels about it. Let's hear it!

Answer (score 9):

It seems [bibtex](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibtex) is a subset of [reference-managers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-managers). I don't see why we need to spilt the topic into multiple tiny subsets.

Comment: I agree; any questions for which a "bibtex" tag would be appropriate should likely be moved to the Tex.SE site. That seems to technology-specific here.